# Can't create a view for other user's table despite having select privilege

Tags: oracle, view

I already executed the following commands:

```
grant create view to scott;
conn hr/hr;
grant select on employees to scott;
```

but I conn to scott:

```
create or replace view company_phone_book as
select employee_id emp_id, last_name||','||first_name name, phone_number, email
from hr.employees;
```

gives me the error:

> ORA-01031: insufficient privileges.
>   [image]

Comment: I think you need to grant the select privilege with "grant option" to the table in order to be able to use it in a view.

Comment: which user is executing that create view statement? and in your screenshot, at first you have created view as select * from emp, not employees.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That was very helpful, can you add your solution as an answer so I can upvote it?

Comment: @ JSapkota I am in order to prove the ordinary create a view to normal.

Answer (score 2):

`SCOTT` will have the ability to expose the new view to other users, thus indirectly granting data access on `HR` to other users. `SCOTT` therefore needs `WITH GRANT OPTION` on the grant.

```
GRANT SELECT ON employees TO scott WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think some grants are missing.

Can you try creating the VIEW after giving the following GRANT:

```
GRANT CREATE VIEW TO hr;
```

And also re-structure your CREATE Statement as follows:

```
create or replace view hr.company_phone_book as
select employee_id emp_id, last_name||','||first_name name, phone_number, email
from hr.employees;
```

Hope this works !!